# How was the TV turned on again in Metropia?

Tags: plot-explanation, metropia

I have seen *Metropia (2009)* recently and noticed something that kept bothering me.
Towards the end of the movie, we see Roger (the protagonist) setting at the desk of Stefan, after he was killed and his ID given to Roger.
When he switches on the monitor at his desk, he sees the room where his girlfriend is. At that moment, Karl is seen rejecting the phone call to her mobile and switching it to silent mode.

We later see his girlfriend (Anna) entering the room and inquire about her phone. Karl misleads her by claiming it was the TV. He also tries to seduce her before he decides to switch off the TV. Thus, roger can't know what is going on.

After a while, the monitor is switched back on, and we see Karl knocking on the door from which Anna came in.
The weird part is: who switched it on?
Did Karl switch it on?
If so, then why? 
He is pre-occupied with Anna and should not have the latest care about what's on tv, especially if he is the one who switched it off.

Did Anna switch it on and then instantly went out of the room and locked the door at the same time?

Something is missing.